# Spring + WildFly+ IBM MQ Cofiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wildfly, ibm-mq

I have Spring Web-aplication, deployed on WildFly 10 server. I need to add the ability to send and receive messages to/from IBM MQ server (now version 7.5, but the version will be updated soon to 9).
I read a lot of documentation, how to configure WildFly(JBoss) or spring application, but there is several approaches to do that, and I confused which is the best practice.

What I need to write in the **standalone.xml** file? Is such configuration is correct:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/jms/jmsConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="jmsConnectionFactory">
                        <config-property name="channel">
                            SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="hostName">
                            myserver
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="transportType">
                            CLIENT
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">
                            QM3
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="port">
                            1414
                        </config-property>
                        <security>
                            <application/>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        </validation>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/jms/FROMS1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="FROMS1">
                        <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            FROMS1
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                            QM3
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/jms/TOS1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="TOS1">
                        <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            TOS1
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                            QM3
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

Or it is no need to configure resource adapter in WildFly and I can cofigure it in application?

In **pom.xml** I add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In some articles I saw dependencies for **com.ibm.mqjms** and **com.ibm.mq.jmqi**, are they needed?

Next step is to cofigure **spring-servlet.xml**. How to do It? 
Which connection factory to use **com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory** or **spring SingleConnectionFactory**?

How get and put messages from/to queues within application?